# How would i know which object has been updated on model.@each EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Im trying to change an object property in a list of object and would like to get that object right after it was changed.

My approach is to observe property changes on that list through `model.@each.property_1`

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  onModelProperty1Change: function(){
    // How can i get that particular object after one of it 
    // property was changed inside here?
    //
    // do some database action to the object...

  }.observes('model.@each.property'),

});
```

I wonder if this is a right approach. Or should I go for change event on element instead? Either way I need to know it is possible to get that object inside `observes` helper.

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting is not possible without adding additional state that you can "diff" when the observer fires and subsequently update. I would not recommend this approach

Instead, the function that changes the object should then call the update code. This is easily accomplished with actions + services. Let's assume whatever triggers your update sends the index of the model to update and the new value (I'm just demonstrating here since you didn't include how your object changes)

```
actions: {
  updateModelAtIndex(index, prop){
    let modelToUpdate = this.get('model')[index];
    modelToUpdate.set('property', prop);

    let service = this.get('someInjectedService');
    service.save(modelToUpdate);
  }
}
```

Now, in old ember versions with 2 way binding, it wasn't as easy to intercept these changes (when they're the result of a bound form field changing), and you had to rely on observers as your current code does. Converting to 1 way bound approach where the form element emits the action, and you only update the model in an action handler fixes this.

Comment: In a list of item a model property change upon updating data on input control, say we would like to edit the property `name` in a particular row. This one is a common pattern but effective on this case since `@each` aren't design to detect which row was changed but only to observes if one of those items was updated.

Comment: @Roel show me an ember-twiddle that demonstrates the issue. I believe what I suggested would help you orchestrate the update + edit of the property by abandoning two way binding (assuming you arent Ember 1.x). Your input field emits, say `onChange` at which point you set the name and trigger the update from a single action handler, rather than let a two way bound input update the field for you